# Lightning Tree Grid (LWC) - invoke onclick method for button type column

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

In LWC tree grid I have created a column type "button". Does anybody know how to invoke the onclick method on it ?

Thank you  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowaction attribute to capture button click.
Rowaction: The event fired when a row-level action is run.